# Reuse Quartz jobs with different job data?

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I have a usecase where I want to use the same job (same job class and key with `@DisallowConcurrentExecution` to avoid concurrent execution), but I want to use a different value for one of my job data fields.

The following causes an exception upon scheduling them due to job key conflict:

```
JobDetail ingestJob = newJob(MyJob.class)
                .withIdentity("jobkey", "jobGroup")
                .usingJobData(JOB_USER_KEY, "value")
                .build();

JobDetail ingestJob = newJob(MyJob.class)
                .withIdentity("jobkey", "jobGroup)
                .usingJobData("jobField", "differentValue")
                .build();
```

Is this possible?  Whats the best way of achieving this?  I don't want job data from one job scheduling to affect another, and scheduling can be done by different threads in my application.

Answer (score 0):

Of course right after posting this I find that triggers can also have job data via `TriggerBuilder`'s `.usingJobData` method, allowing me to safely reuse a job with different job data.